# Update Data Using Modal on Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I want to create  edit data on laravel using a modal for view . 
but i dont know how to catch  one data on on my edit form .

i build controller like edit data on another page ( not using modals  )

```
 public function index()
{
    $ipsrs = DB::table('ipsrs')->pluck('nama_bagian','id');
    $belum_kerjakan = Aduan::with('users')->where('status','Belum Dikerjakan')->get();
    $dalam_proses   = Aduan::with('users')->where('status','Sedang Dikerjakan')->get();
    $selesai        = Aduan::with('users')->where('status','Selesai')->get();
    return view('admin.admin_dashboard',[
        'belum_dikerjakan' => $belum_kerjakan,
        'dalam_proses'     => $dalam_proses,
        'selesai'          => $selesai,
        'ipsrs'            => $ipsrs,
    ]);

}


public function change_aduan($id) 
{

    $aduan = Aduan::findOrFail($id);
    if (!$aduan)
    abort(404);

    return view('admin.admin_dashboard',[
        'aduan' => $aduan
    ]);
}
```

this route . ( but i dont know where i used this route ?

```
 Route::get('admin_dashboard', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin_dashboard');  // this route for view table
 Route::get('change/{id}','AdminController@change_aduan')->name('change_aduan');   // this route "will" showing data on this modals
```

my View

```
 <div class="card-body" align='center'>
        <div class="card-body p-0">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
              <thead align="center">
                <tr class="satu">
                  <th style="width: 3%">#</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%">Nama Unit</th>
                  <th style="width: 15%">Tanggal Aduan</th>
                  <th style="width: 8%">Nama Pengadu</th>
                  <th style="width: 8%">Tujuan Aduan</th>
                  <th style="width: 30%">Isi Aduan </th>
                  {{-- <th>Label</th> --}}
                  <th style="width: 5%">Status</th>
                  <th style="width: 5%">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @php
                  $no=0;
                 @endphp
                 @foreach ($belum_dikerjakan as $i)
                <tr>
                  <td> {{++$no}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->users->nama_unit}}</td>
                  <td> {{$i->created_at}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->nama_pengadu}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->ipsrs->nama_bagian}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->aduan}}</td>
                  <td><span class="badge bg-danger"> Belum Dikerjakan</span></td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$i->id}}" data-target="#modal-lg" > // modals button
                    Action
                  </button></td>
                </tr> 
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title"> Change Status  </h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            {{-- Here this Form --}}
             {{-- {{$aduan->nama_pengadu}} --}} // this Line is failur
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
```

i dont know how to next step , on another tutorial this data is can showed using {{ $data->name }} , but in my view cant do this . whats wrong ,and how i can solved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not far off.  I believe the issue you are having is that you are trying to pull the `name` field from a **collection** instead of an **object**.

In your **Blade** file, this line:

```
<td> {{$i->users->nama_unit}}</td>
```

is essentially saying: for this iteration (`$i`) of `$belum_dikerjakan`, give me ALL the `users` and tell me the name of the *collection* of users.  The collection doesn't have a `name` field.  Because you have many users for this `$belum_dikerjakan`, you will either need to loop on all of them, identify the specific user by id (example `$i->users->where('id', 1)->first()->nama_unit`), or take the first one randomly:

```
$i->users->first()->nama_unit
```

What these examples do, is it pulls a single **object** user instead of a collection, and thus you have the field `name` on that **object**.

This line:

```
 <td> {{$i->ipsrs->nama_bagian}} </td>
```

doesn't look like a relationship at all, and you may need to refactor this into either a relation on `$belum_dikerjakan`, or remove it from the loop and use it independently, but this is a separate issue I think.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yess this is " I think you are not far off. I believe the issue you are having is that you are trying to pull the name field from a collection instead of an object. " true . i want to edit 1 data from table , but i didnt know how to catch just 1 data on this table .  this   {{ $data->name }} its just example , i not add this on my code .

Comment: I think my answer will solve a couple of problems for you (the `nama_unit` on the `$i->users->` for example).  However, the issue with just pulling the data into a form, and *loading* that data into `{{$aduan->nama_pengadu}}` is a much bigger issue.  You'll need to leave that information OFF the main page and off the modal at inital loading.  Then you will need to use ajax to load the specific `$aduan` you need based on some type of user action.  You may benefit from reading about how to call AJAX using JS, and then how to route it to your controller and update the modal in Laravel :)